black screen after choosing "try or install ubuntu"
it's a dual boot with windows for ubuntu it gave me the black screen more than 30 minutes ago and can't find solutions so is it safe to shut the laptop down through the power button or not?

The options to "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" only appear when the LiveUSB installer is running. They do not appear after a successful install. If this is really a "dual-boot," then Ubuntu has not been installed properly. It's safe to poweroff, as you will need to reinstall anyway.

Alternately, perhaps you mean that you intend to install a dual-boot, and you are currently booted from a LiveUSB. That can powered off at any time.

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

All computer systems are designed to be safely shut down by unplugging from electricity, because in many locations it is simply impossible to have a reliable source of electricity 24/7. This may result in some data loss if you were working on something that you did not save, but your operating system and hardware will not be harmed.

Sorry, I have to downvote, but this is definitely wrong. I've seen quite a few PC break from power failures. Mostly broken power supplys and broken HDDs. Most could be recovered, but some were completely unreadable and we had to restore from backups.

I mean, shit happens, but this is rather the corner case than the design.
